# Converting HttpClient version 3 ProtocolSocketFactory use to version 4

Tags: apache, httpclient

I have some code that uses HttpClient version 3. I would like to come up with a version 4 equivalent. I believe 4.0 but any version 4 would be helpful.

```
ProtocolSocketFactory psf = myObj.getPSF();
httpClient.getHostConfiguration().setHost(host, port, new Protocol("http", psf, 80));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this by adding a scheme and making my own SchemeSocketFactory.

```
Scheme myScheme = new Scheme("https", port, new MySchemeSocketFactory());
httpClient.getConnectionManager().getSchemeRegistry().register(myScheme);
```